# Bundler: Create Gem - Default Contact Info Source?

Tags: ios, ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemspecs

I followed this guide to build my first Ruby Gem:

http://bundler.io/v1.12/guides/creating_gem.html

Everything worked as expected, but I have one question: I noticed that Bundler auto-magically pulled my personal contact info from somewhere (I'm on a Mac) and used that to build the gem.  An example of a file containing this info:

```
gem_name.gemspec
```

I don't want it to default to using my personal contact info (such as my personal email address, etc.) as I build more gems.  I want it to use my company's info by default.  I'm guessing/hoping that there is some data file somewhere that I can set this default info, to be used on all further new gem builds?  Or maybe some other way to set these default values???

I realize that I can edit this info after the scaffold builds, but I want to automate it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler pulls that info from git so just set your name in your `~/.gitconfig` globally:

```
[user]
  email = my@workemail.com
  name = MyName
```

or you could set it locally to that repo via `./git/config`.